# How to make a document.getElementById value into an integer variable, not a string?

Tags: javascript

I want to pass in a value, obtained from the an html object, convert that value into an integer so I can run arithmetic on it before outputting it.  As my code stands now, it just adds them up like a string.  So a value of 5 + a modifier of 100 ends up equaling = 5100, not 105.

Here's my form code:

```
<form>
    Add Amount: <select id="addTweets">
    <option value=5>5</option>
    <option value=10>10</option>
    <option value=15>15</option>
    </select>
    </br>
    <input type="button" value="Add It" onclick="addTweet()" />
</form>
```

Here's my script:

```
function addTweet()
{
var mod = 100;
var results = document.getElementById("addTweets").value;
results += mod;

document.getElementById("tweetsOutput").innerHTML = results;
}
```

Comment: Your title was *very* confusing. "But... but... `getElementById` is a function... and its result is a DOM element... what string?!?" Also, everyone using `parseInt` without the `10` in the second argument, shame on you :p (not important in this case, but forms bad habits)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The unary plus (`+`) coerces its operand into a number:

```
var results = +document.getElementById("addTweets").value;
    ...

typeof( results ); // number
```

Comment: Into a number to be acurate

Comment: does this work for floats too?

Comment: @wbinky It should.

Answer (score 3):

Use parseInt:

```
var results = document.getElementById("addTweets").value;
var intResults = parseInt(results, 10) + mod;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `parseInt`

```
var results = parseInt(document.getElementById("addTweets").value);
```

Answer (score 1):

just add parseInt, then you could add it normally

```
 var results = parseInt(document.getElementById("addTweets").value);
```

EDIT:

parseInt alternate, you can use "|0" use bitwise-or zero

```
 var results = document.getElementById("addTweets").value|0;
```

Comment: i pretty sure that i've answer it first ^^

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var valResult = document.getElementById("addTweets").value; // get the value of the field

var results = parseInt(valResult) + mod; // convert the value to int to do calculation

document.getElementById("addTweets").value = results; // assign results to the field value
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can convert the string numerical values into integers by doing a mathematical operation on it:

```
x = "9"; //String numerical value
y = 10;//integer value
alert(x+y)// output 910;
x = x*1;
alert(x+y) // output 19
```

Checkout this [demo](http://jsbin.com/boxinekixe/edit?html,output)