# Javascript not taking value of input number

Tags: javascript, html, math

I'm making a programme in javascript where a user has to enter numbers, and the computer will do calculations for them based on the numbers.
However, when I'm programming Javascript to add two inputted numbers, its simply placing them next to each other and not adding.
for example, when it has to add 4 + 4, the output is 44, not 8.

```
<form>
    <p> Give side 1</p>
 <br>
<input type="number"  id="side1">  
<br><br>
<p> Give side 2</p>
 <br>
<input type="number"  id="side2">  
 <br><br>
  <p> Give side 3</p>
  <br>
 <input type="number"  id="side3">  
<br><br>

<button type="button" onClick="my()"> Calculate</button>
<p id="sum"></p>


</form>


</center>
<script type="text/javascript">
function my() {
var a= document.getElementById("side1").value;
var b= document.getElementById("side2").value;
var c= document.getElementById("side3").value;
var d= a + b + c;
    document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML="The are o the triangle is " + "" + d;
}




</script>
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13693580/how-to-make-a-document-getelementbyid-value-into-an-integer-variable-not-a-stri.

Answer (score 2):

This is working. You just have to use `parseInt`:

```
function my() {
    var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("side1").value, 10);
    var b = parseInt(document.getElementById("side2").value, 10);
    var c = parseInt(document.getElementById("side3").value, 10);
    var d = a + b + c;
    document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = "The are o the triangle is " + "" + d;
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8bgjnex7/3/)

**Ref:**

[parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Answer (score 0):

the value you get from `document.getElementById("").value` is type of String.

to sum up, you have to change it to int,

while there are many way to do this.

```
var a= document.getElementById("side1").value - 0
```

or

```
var a= parseInt(document.getElementById("side1").value)
```

(this one is suggested for case of invalid input)

or

```
var a= document.getElementById("side1").value * 1;
```

Comment: Its working fine now, but when I input a number more than 27, its returns value "NaN". Please help.