# JavaScript var not being recognized as a number

Tags: javascript, var

I have an HTML div, which I use JavaScript to retrieve the value from, as below:

```
    var oCreditStatus = document.getElementById('creditStatusField');

    var oOrigValue = oCreditStatus.value;
```

var oOrigValue will always be a number, and sometimes 0 (Zero).

I now want to increment or decrement the number by 1. However, when I do the following:

```
var oNewValue = oCreditStatus.value + 1;
```

I get the value 01, then 011, which is wrong as I want 1,2.

I know it is not recognizing it as a number, but how do I get it to do so.

Comment: `oCreditStatus`'s value is stored as a string. You will need to convert it to a  number before adding with it: `var oOrigValu = Number(oCreditStatus.value)`

Comment: You may also use: `var oNewValue = +oCreditStatus.value + 1;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a document.getElementById value into an integer variable, not a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13693580/how-to-make-a-document-getelementbyid-value-into-an-integer-variable-not-a-stri)

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with this question and no reason to mark it down. Anyone who ever voted down, do you wish to explain your reasons? @JamesThorpe ?

Comment: @Alex I didn't downvote it - that was someone else.  Just pointed out the potential duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. Javascript engine will read it as a text/string. You've to use following code:

Edit. Use a radix (base 10) Thanks to @James for revision.

```
var oCreditStatus = document.getElementById('creditStatusField');

var oOrigValue = parseInt(oCreditStatus.value, 10); // use parseFloat for decimal.
```

Comment: Worth making sure you [specify a radix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Octal_interpretations_with_no_radix) when using `parseInt`

Comment: Add the radix to `parseInt()` or there will be surprises for some inputs.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

> var oOrigValue will always be a number, and sometimes 0 (Zero).

Just pass it to `Number` function since `oOrigValue` is always a number. (Note: `0` is also a number)

```
var oOrigValue = Number(oCreditStatus.value);
```

There are several other ways of doing the same by prefixing it with `+` and `~~`

Answer (score 2):

In fact `oOrigValue` is not a number, it's a string. To be able to add another number to it, you'll have to parse it first. There is several methods to do it:

```
var parsedValue = parseInt(oOrigValue, 10); // remember about the second parameter - the radix
```

or simpler, but less readable

```
var parsedValue = +oOrigValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

try to this

```
var oCreditStatus = document.getElementById('creditStatusField').value*1;
```

Comment: This is going to try multiplying an `HTMLElement` by `1`, which doesn't make sense. You probably meant to multiply the element's `.value` attribute. However, that is still an unclear way of converting to a `Number`. Better to use one of the built-in parse functions.

Comment: This would work, when being applied to the value and not the DOM element. The `parseInt()` solution is, however, clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse `oCreditStatus.value` as an `int`

```
var oNewValue = parseInt(oCreditStatus.value) + 1;
```