# Need to convert string to int in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div id="remainingfunds">
  <p>Remaining Funds: $<span id="remainingfundsnumber">500</span></p>
</div><!--remainingfunds-->

<div id="subtotal">
  <p>Subtotal: $<span id="subtotalnumber">0</span></p>
</div><!--subtotal-->
```

```
remainingfundsnumber=parseInt(remainingfundsnumber);

subtotal = parseInt(subtotalnumber);
```

Obviously not that simple. Help me out, please.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please make your question clearer? the tag says Javascript but the title says Java

Comment: get element by id, then get the html content and do the rest as in ur code

Comment: may be duplicate of [How to make a document.getElementById value into an integer variable, not a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13693580/how-to-make-a-document-getelementbyid-value-into-an-integer-variable-not-a-stri)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a document.getElementById value into an integer variable, not a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13693580/how-to-make-a-document-getelementbyid-value-into-an-integer-variable-not-a-stri)

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.getElementById()` to get an element that you want with the required ID and `innerHTML` to get its inner html data

```js
remainingfundsnumber = parseInt(document.getElementById("remainingfundsnumber").innerHTML);
subtotal = parseInt(document.getElementById("subtotalnumber").innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="remainingfunds">
  <p>Remaining Funds: $<span id="remainingfundsnumber">500</span></p>
</div><!--remainingfunds-->

<div id="subtotal">
  <p>Subtotal: $<span id="subtotalnumber">0</span></p>
</div><!--subtotal-->
```